# Nslcd:cannot open nsswitch.conf

Tags: permissions, pam, ldap

When I try to run

`systemctl status nslcd`

An error in between the lines appear and it looks like this:

`cannot open /etc/nsswitch.conf: Permission denied`

I haven't change the permissions for neither of the files, and I am currently running the machine as root. Anyone knows the reason for this error and if it can impact the machine somehow (it probably does)?

---

Of course, when I change the permissions for anyone to read the file, this error does not appear anymore, but still I would not like the file to be readable by everyone.

Comment: AFAIK the default permissions/ownership for `/etc/nsswitch.conf` are `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root` - is that not the case on your system?

Comment: @steeldriver No, in my case it is -rw-------